# Connecting BMP280 sensor to microcontroller

Tags: sensors, i2c

I am building my own board with integrated pressure sensor.
(microcontroller is 3V3 logic)

I want to know which parts do i need. In datasheet there are only 2 capacitors but on breakout board there are also 4 resistors.

Also in datasheet are 2 100 nF capacitors and on breakout board are 1uF and 0,1uF.

schematics from datasheet:
[image]

breakout board schematics:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capacitors are just decoupling capacitors. The value is not that critical. 100nF are good values to use.  On the breakout they have used just one pair of decoupling capacitors but use that pair for both power pins. The datasheet has one decoupling capacitor for each pin. You can do it either way. Personally I'd do it the datasheet way, but for a small board it really doesn't make much difference.

The resistors are a different matter. The BMP280 can work in a number of communication modes, and which mode you have it in dictates what resistors are needed.

R1 is used to place it into I2C mode. R4 is used to set the I2C address. R2 and R3 are the pullup resistors on the I2C bus. They aren't really part of the BMP280 circuit, but part of any I2C circuit in general.

R1 and R4 could be replaced by direct connections to VCC and GND respectively, but by having resistors gives you the ability to override them and use SPI instead of I2C should you wish it.